Error : Unable to find "/drive name/username@domain. please check the spelling and try again
I am new to Linux OS. I have installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on one of our office desktops and joined it to our office Windows Active Directory Domain.
Now I can log into this system using AD Domain user credentials, but as soon as I click on the Files icon I get the below error where the drive name is H which is our shared driver in Windows File Server
Error: Unable to find "/drive name/username@domain. please check the spelling and try again
I do not know anything about Ubuntu or Linux, Please help me to resolve this issue and be able to access windows file servers path from ubuntu system.

Did you install the required tools on the Ubuntu machine to handle Windows files?


Installed sssd-tools which was required to add the ubuntu system to windows active directory, using the below command

apt install -y sssd-ad sssd-tools realm adcli
2.Configured Keberos to able to be the part of realm, using below command
cat > /etc/krb5.conf <<E0F
[libdefaults]
default_realm=EXAMPLE.COM
rdns=false

Okay that's fine but did you install the tools for samba and cifs utilities?

no, now I tried with the below commands

sudo apt update

result : 3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
next, I used the command

sudo apt upgrade

result : The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-core ubuntu-release-upgarder-gtk
0-upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded
Please guide how to process further
